# AVAudioSession setActive: failed after interruption ended

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudiosession, audioqueue

I added notification to listen to interruptions form others like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(audioInterruption:)
                                         name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                       object:nil];


- (void)audioInterruption:(NSNotification *)audioInterruptNotification{
NSLog(@"interrupted!");

   NSDictionary *interruptionDictionary = [audioInterruptNotification userInfo];
   NSNumber *interruptionType = (NSNumber *)[interruptionDictionary valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey];

   if ([interruptionType intValue] == AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan) {
       NSLog(@"Interruption started");

   } else if ([interruptionType intValue] == AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded){
       NSLog(@"Interruption ended");
       BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES withOptions:NO error:nil];
       if (!success) {
          NSLog(@"avaudio session set active failed");
       } 

   } else {
       NSLog(@"Something else happened");
   }
}
```

When interruption happens, the notification is fine but it fails to 
`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES withOptions:NO error:nil];`.So why it happened and how could I resume playing after interruptions(I used AudioQueue to play or record instead of AVAudioPlayer)?

Comment: I also notice my app doesn't identify when the interruption is being ended either. I'd like to figure out why.